# How do logarithmic measurements affect the Wilcoxon rank-sum test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matlab, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have some measurements and I want to try the Wilcoxon rank-sum test. The units are bels. The P-value of the test is 0.03 when the units are in bels(log_10 of raw data) but when I raise the data to power of 10 the P-value is 0.4. Which one is more reliable and I should trust? How does the logarithm affect the Wilcoxon rank-sum test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give an example of how the ranks would change upon taking the logarithms?

Comment: In case i am not mistaken the ranks shouldn't change since logarithm is a monotonic function. The only thing that changes is the distribution of samples and so the probability of the hypothesis.

Comment: Since the ranks don't change, neither does the Wilcoxon rank-sum test.  If you got different values then you should be looking for a computational error.

Comment: Just to make sure, you use the Wilcoxon rank sum test not the Wilcoxon signed-rank test right? In addition, you say "*raise the data to the power of 10(" while your formula is using `log10`, this implies $log_{10}(x) = y \rightarrow x = 10^y$ not $ x= y^{10}$. Finally, you do raise both of your samples correct?

Comment: Yes. It is probably a computational error as @whuber said but i am still unable to find.

Comment: If the data-set is not large, please post your data and the two sets of answers you got; otherwise you leave us to guess at possible causes; at the least we can confirm what answers you should have obtained. [I took the liberty of editing "Bells" to "bels" (the unit of the base 10 log of a power-ratio, of which the one-tenth part - the *decibel* is the more widely known unit).]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wilcoxon rank-sum test is unaffected by monotonic-increasing transformations of the data (such as exponentiation and logarithms) -- since they don't change the rank order, they cannot change the statistic, and hence the p-value should be unaltered.

There are any number of possible reasons why you might have seen a change in p-value:

- if you computed $x^{10}$ instead of $10^x$ (your question implies you might have) and some $x$'s were negative, that would change the rank order
- If you actually calculated the log-data from the unlogged data (rather than the other way around, as you describe) your data might have inadvertently contain numbers that are zero or negative, which precludes being able to meaningfully take logs; this could lead to the omission of some data and some programs mightn't warn you about the problem (or perhaps it did but you didn't pay attention to the warning)
- you might have accidentally computed some other quantity such as a Wilcoxon signed rank test
- you might have somehow changed your data along the way in a manner which impacts the ranks (other than those already mentioned)
- you may have called the function incorrectly without realizing it
- you may not have treated both samples identically
- the software you're using might be doing a form of resampling (in effect a randomization test) to compute the p-value in the presence of ties and the number of resamples used might have been much too low.
- the software you're using might possibly contain an error

$\vdots$

and so on (a complete list isn't really possible - there's too many ways for something weird to come in). Without additional clues we really won't be able to pin down the cause.

Comment: Since the *original* units are bels, evidently the problem lies in exponentiating rather than taking logs.

Comment: @whuber good point; I wasn't paying sufficiently close attention. I have edited to include a possibility for that attempted exponentiation and rephrased otherwise

Comment: Your first bullet is now a very interesting guess!

Comment: At last I found the mistake in my code. Actually it performed the test on the mean of every 20 samples. So the exponentiation does affect the test by affecting the mean, since mean(data) <> mean (10^(data)).

Comment: Why would you perform the Wilcoxon test on mean of samples? It is such an odd thing to do that we'd be unlikely to guess that's what you'd do -- and it's exactly the sort of thing I was referring to when I said we'd need "additional clues" to pin down the cause. (Indeed, why would you not think that was important enough to mention? Or do you mean that this was the mistake?)